Grub Shutdown and Reboot Entry's
Hello dear people,
I want to add Shutdown and Reboot options to Grub.
I added
menuentry "Reboot" {

reboot

}

menuentry "Shut Down" {

halt

}

to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and remade the config with sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but the menuentrys don't show up. They're not in the config file.
Other files are mentioned by name in the finished config, like 30_uefi_firmware, mine doesn't get any recognition.
The other files have executable permissions, if I give them to my file with chmod +x the system reboots immediately after remaking the config, and the entry's still aren't there.
I checked around the Internet and this is how other people do it. I'm pretty sure I did it that way before and it worked, I don't know why it doesn't work now.
Do the files need specific rights or owners?
I'm running:
Arch with the 6.6.49-1-lts kernel with Grub 2 on version 2.12-2. I'm only booting in UEFI, my root partition is Encrypted with LUKS, the boot partition isn't.
Help is greatly appreciated.
Greetns

Please do not litter the title.

Files under /etc/grub.d are not config snippets – they are scripts that run during generation in order to print out a config snippet. So if you put a 'reboot' command in the file, it will likewise run during config generation, with the result you saw. (It probably also complained about 'menuitem' being an unknown command.)
If you want some text to become part of the generated config, your script has to echo it (or do something else that prints text), that is, you need to echo "menuitem aaa {" and echo "reboot".
#!/bin/sh
echo "menuitem Reboot {"
echo "  reboot"
echo "}"

The end goal is that if you directly run your 40_custom as if a shell script, it should print the config.
There are various shell features such as heredocs that make it easier than repeating echos. The original 40_custom file that comes with GRUB had a specific line in it:
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

...which means "stop interpreting the script and print out everything from the 3rd line". This trick lets you simply add the GRUB menuitems –but only as long as you add them after the exec, not before.
A somewhat simpler approach would be to use a heredoc:
#!/bin/sh
cat <<'END'
menuitem reboot {
  reboot
}
END


Thank you very much, i used the last heredoc and gave the file executable permission, because now i know its a script not a config file. I had to change the "menuitem" in your cmmand to "menuentry", ofc. but this solved my problem!
Thank you for your time.
